# wordpress 403 error on admin login page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

I've got a problem here.
I have a wordpress site and accidentally changed the http to https and I am not sure that I could change it back.
What is sure that it loged me out and when I reload the admin login page it throws an error that my connection is not private and after that I got a 403 Forbidden page.

I have access to the FTP and tried to change the wp_config file, no success. Tried adding this:

`define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`

it only made the admin page reachable when I entered the user and pass it reloaded the login page.

I also tried to delete the .htaccess file, perhaps it is corrupted, but did not help.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: is site is working will other then admin?

Comment: I am the only admin

Comment: share the site url

Comment: here it is: [link](http://www.itinero.eu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to enter the admin page finally!
So I added these two lines to wp_admin.php:

`define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`

afterward deleted the .htaccess file, then deleted browsing history, cleared cache and cookies.
After all of this I could enter the admin page.

Then I went to options/general and options/permalinks and saved the setting, it generated a .htaccess file and now it is working.

I also tried removing the two added lines from wp_admin.php after all, but I broke the page so they are going to stay for a while.

Comment: What is the location of wp_admin.php?

Answer (score 3):

Look in your Wordpress database,
there is a table called **wp_options** and an entry in option_name called '**siteurl**' as the name suggests it holds the URL of your site. Change this back to http and you should be good. There is also an entry for home which will also have a URL for your site to be updated.
Alternatively and also a better option, get a site certificate so that you can use https.

Comment: Thanks, I first I looked fo the wp_optios and I could not locate it. Any idea where can it be hiding, or perhaps is it missing?

Comment: I only find in the wp_admin folder an options.php file. could it be the one we are looking for?

Comment: wp_options is not a file it is a database table. when your WP was created a mySQL database was required. If you have a hosting control panel there is usually a link for databases / mySQL or phpAdmin.
If you cannot get access to your DB, then I'm not aware of any other way to fix this.